# REST API invoked from backbone returns empty response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and trying a simple example with an app that uses the backbone js backend and  invokes a rest API (created with rails) that returns a json object. If I type the rest api URL on the browser it successfully returns with the JSON data. However when I launch my app, I can see that the API is returning an empty response (but it returns a 200 OK status). If I replace this URL with the twitter search api then that is also successfully returning data. SO the problem seems to be only with the rails REST API. Here is my backbone code:

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend();

var ProductList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Product,
url: 'http://hvo-lnx.cisco.com:7777/product_families.json'
});

var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
template: _.template($('#prodlist_template').html()),
render: function(eventName) {
_.each(this.model.models, function(product){
    var lProductName = product.attributes['name'];
    var lTemplate = this.template(product.toJSON());

    $(this.el).append(lTemplate);
  }, this);
return this;
}
 });


var lProducts = new ProductList;

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "body",

  render: function(){
    var lProductsView = new ProductView({model:lProducts});
    var lHtml = lProductsView.render().el;
    $('#products').html(lHtml);
  },

initialize: function(){
   var lOptions = {};
   lOptions.success = this.render;
   lProducts.fetch(lOptions);
}
});

var App = new AppView;
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol id="products">
            <script type="text/template" id="prodlist_template">
                  <li><%= name %></li>
            </script>
        </ol>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/prodtest.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I replace the URL with http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=NYC&callback=? and change the attribute fields, then that works ok. Has anyone else experienced this problem? I would really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: can you share the rails code ? if your backbone works fine with twitter and not with rails so its seems to be a server side issue

Comment: I also wanted to add that the error callback in fetch is always executed even though the API returns a 200 OK (but empty) response.

Comment: I just found that if I change my API to http://hvo-lnx.cisco.com:7777/product_families.json?callback=? then it will return a response. Still have the problem where the fetch error callback is always executed even though the api returns a success

Comment: I think you might be running into Cross-Origin security issues.  You have to setup your Backbone Model a little bit differently to support jsonp apis.  See https://gist.github.com/DenisOS/1245613 for one such example.

Comment: Thanks for the response everyone.

Turns out I need to wrap my json response with the callback paramerter passed. So once I added that to the controller, it works. So something like this:

    `class PostsController < ApplicationController
  
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render :json => @posts, :callback =>
                                              params[:callback] }
      end`

Comment: Another follow-up question though. Is this the right way to do this? I came across a cross-origin security issue which sounds like what I was experiencing as well. That involved more extensive changes to the rails app though.